# How do i redirect the user from login in facebook to a Home screen?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My goal is very simple, redirect or navigate the user to a main screen once he/she is logged in.

I'm using Facebook IOS SDK to create that login button

[image]

Once the user has logged in the button will change to logout, my goal is to redirect the user to a home screen

[image]

I wrote some code and it has some API calls to save the data that the app receives from Facebook IOS SDK (etc. Email, firstname, lastname..)

```
  func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        print("Login")

        // if token exist , check the database whether the user's facebook id exist or not
        if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
            fetchFacebookProfile() // this function simply store the data from facebook to the database, nothing fancy
        }


    }
```

My real question is How do i redirect the user to a new screen after he/she has logged in to facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to answer this question, here is one:

In AppDelegate.swift add the following code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //1
    Data.ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock { (authData) -> Void in
      //2
      if authData == nil {
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginScene") as! LoginVC
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = ViewController
      }
    }
    return true
  }
```

1. `Data.ref` is just a reference to the database in which the user have its token
2. `authData` is an `Boolean` that indicate if the user is logged in or not and we use the observation block to monitor changes in `authData`

In your storyboard, you want your `storyboard entry point` to point to your `main screen` and if the user is not logged in, the `AppDelegate` will direct the user to the `login screen`. This way the user that already logged in does not need to go via the login screen every time he uses the App.

[image: Screen Shot of how the storyboard should look like in this case]